# python two variables - find which one is closest to zero

Tags: python, numpy, comparison

I have two variables  - Value1 and Value2 that are set using previous functions in my code.
I want to select and output the variable that is closest to zero.

The variables change every time I run my code so can be decimal or integer format and positive/negative values.

I have seen examples of using lambda and numpy but I'm new to python so I'm unsure how to implement these correctly.  Examples I have seen have the values in an array or list but mine are two separate variables.

Comment: What if the values are equidistant to zero?

Answer (score 4):

You can choose the one with the smallest absolute value:

```
a = -4
b = 3

min(a, b, key=abs)

# 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with a `key` parameter that applies the `abs` function (i.e., the distance from zero):

```
x = min([value1, value2], key=abs)
```